Volume of Solid of Revolution Referred to by a Graph
I need to refer to the figure and find the volume generated by rotating the given region about the specified line. a is equal to 2, b is equal to 3, and we are rotating the region R1 about OC. enter image description here
I believe that the correct approach here is to use the "shell" method, wherein we get cross-sections that are parallel to the axis of rotation (the y-axis), and then multiply the integral from the x coordinate bounds, of the function (in this case 2x^3) by 2pi.
However, when I set up the integral 2pi times the integral from 0 to 1 of 2x^3, I got pi as the answer, which was incorrect.
I'm not even sure if I'm taking the right approach to solving this question at this point. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

When integrating using the shell method you have to multiply the height function (in this case, $2x^3$) by the radius function (in this case, $x$, since the axis of rotation is the y-axis).
